# Why are Fallout 4 Questions getting so many down votes?

Tags: discussion

Basically what the title says. The majority of the questions for Fallout 4 have very bad scores. They seem like okay questions in my opinion. Is it because Fallout 4 is so new? In that case, should questions about new games be looked down upon?

Comment: My suspicion is that some users downvoted because they suspected that users were using a pirated copy. I don't know the details, but from what I read the game was available in some timezones earlier than in the US, and some people used VPNs to unlock early. Several of the early questions not by the particular user mentioned in the answer below also received downvotes, though they have a positive score now.

Comment: Of [over 250 questions](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fallout-4), only 5 of them have negative scores.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft When this question was first asked, I think at least 50% of the Fallout 4 questions had negative scores. Keep in mind that this was also the day the game was released.

Comment: Why wasn't this question down voted?? ;-)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It is difficult to say with any degree of certainty, as each user has their own reason/justification for their downvote. And across several questions, it is difficult to say if those reasons remain constant. However, of the questions, [the one sitting at -10 currently](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/242499/understanding-fallout-4s-ending), I might be able to provide some context: The user has a bit of a history in asking the [meaning of an ending](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241176/understanding-halo-5s-legendary-ending) almost immediately upon the game's release. This is not inherently frowned upon, if you genuinely do not understand a game's ending after having reached it; it is perfectly reasonable to enquire about it.

However there is also a bit of a history of rules lawyering, a certain degree of "I'm not touching you!" (with a finger hovering centimeters in front of the target's face), that has eroded a fair bit of our assumption that the questions are asked in good faith.

Are the questions being asked because it is a genuine problem the user has/had, or are they asked because the user *can* ask them? Ultimately they are acceptable questions, as they are not closed (despite a couple close-votes that I do not believe will result in closure, or will be overturned if they do), but some of the community is expressing its displeasure.

Comment: I'd say most of it would be genuine downvotes due to questionable utility; the game *literally* just came out.  The only way to have gotten to the ending would be to somehow watch it on Youtube, and asking now isn't actually a problem the user is facing.

Comment: There is a sub-culture on the internet (not just Arqade or one particular user), of people trying to be the 'First' to post/comment/sign up (see the sales for Steam accounts with low ID numbers!). Asking 'easy' questions that will genuinely get a lot of views (and have titles which cater to SEO), is an attempt to garner some reputation, (both in the rep-points sense and the 'street-cred' sense). Should this reason on its own be deserving of a downvote? Probably not. However Is the question a problem the user is facing at this time? Unlikely. Is the question 'useful'? Probably Not. (cont.)

Comment: That's probably why it's downvoted so heavily. Not because 'the user has a history of posting these', but because the question itself is fairly poor.

Comment: @Robotnik fair enough, I'd say it's a little of all of the above.

Comment: No comment on the Fallout 4 one (although the spoiler tags seem to be designed to give away the character's identity without explicitly stating it), but the MGSV ending question was at best extremely poorly researched. The question was something explicitly addressed by the game itself in the scene in question. It would be analogous to reaching the end of the 7th Harry Potter book and saying "Wait - he's a wizard?"

Comment: @r3tr0t3hPeNgU1NoFd00m Or, y'know, we could expect users to post questions in good faith and not an attempt to troll other users.  And ask a question only when they actually *encounter* said section.  Hitting the end of the game a day before the game even comes out strains credulity just a little too far.

Comment: There's a stark difference between "not understanding the ending" and asking a question about something that is explained in plain English, directly, by the characters themselves. I find it very difficult to believe anyone would have watched the ending to MGSV and not understand the clearly stated truth of it, but yet also not ask questions about the less clear and non-obvious elements (e.g. things that are references to Metal Gear 1, a game over 25 years old).

Comment: It looks like there has been a comment cleanup but I'd like to add, reading said Fallout 4 ending question, there is no way you could have played the game and got to the end without knowing the answer to each of those questions. The latter half of the game spells out the answer multiple times during non-optional missions...